# Microsoft Teams Deep Link doesn't work properly

Tags: google-chrome, uri, microsoft-teams, deep-linking

I'm trying to open a chat or start a call on Microsoft Teams throw Deep Links.

I used these Deep Links:

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=joe@contoso.com&message=hello

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=joe@contoso.com

If I test them with the test Account 'joe@contoso.com' they work fine instead where I use a real email I get error.

I get ' We've started your group chat but couldn't add xxx@yyy.com ' error when I try to open the Chat.

I get ' There's a problem with the link - Try contacting the person who shared it. ' error when I try to start a call.

(I'm using the free version/account subscription of Microsoft Teams)

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: We are unable to repro the scenario.It working fine from our end.Have you tried it as mention in that document?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot or deeplink which you have tried?

Comment: I simply used some real  email instead of "joe@contoso.com" on the two Deep Links that i put in the question. 
(I also tried to open a chat without the message and i get the same problem).For example i used the email of some people that i  have in my recent chats in Microsoft Teams.

Comment: I am using a Free account/subscription with a work email ( with the domain of the company). Can the free subscription be the problem ?
I am also using the client (i updated it) for Apple Mac.

Comment: For free account it's working fine.Could please update the teams version and then check? If possible could you please share the video for this?

Comment: and also try with this URL > MSTeams:/l/chat/0/0?users=user@user.com

Comment: The application is up to date.
I share you a video on my Google Drive.

This is the link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DknvMyJHpU4VV6qmjF3IGPXdEL5Tc2dM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is the video of the Call Deep Link :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F7Hjv6rpk1IqRD2skHrkxGhysMnog-jO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you approve the access for video?

Comment: I  just approved it.
Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: We are check it with our internal team and let you know once we get any update.

Comment: Ok, I have also sent you an email on sayali.dange92@gmail.com
:)

Comment: bug is resolved. Could you please check it once and confirm the same?
 Microsoft Teams Version 1.6.00.25376 (64-bit)